# jQuery find second tr of table and its childs just using find() method

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        First Want to select this tr
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Then Want to select this one</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have page content in a variable to I have to just use find method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use :nth-child() its index starts with 1
2. Another possible option is to use eq() its index starts with 0

```js
$("table").find("tr:nth-child(2)").find("tr:nth-child(2)").css("color","red")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            First Want to select this tr
            <td>
                <table>`
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Then Want to select this one</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: $(pageContent).find('table[class="myclass"]') actually i have data in variable

Answer (score 1):

A pseudo-selector for the second row can be used to get its content.

```
$.find('table tr:nth-child(2)').html()
```